# How to get to know paragraph color docx python?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I have document where some lines are highlighted. I have managed to open it and get text line by line:

```
doc = Document("/Users/an/PycharmProjects/projects/test.docx")

for para in doc.paragraphs:
   print(para.text)
```

but I don't know how to check which color has each line. Maybe this library has some method for such task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *run* can have a `.highlight_color`, which is perhaps what you're looking for:

```
for p in doc.paragraphs:
    for r in p.runs:
        print(r.font.highlight_color)
```

There is no concept of "line" in Word. There are *paragraphs*, within which there are *runs*. A run is a sequence of characters that shares the same character formatting (aka. "font").

Note that breaks between runs occur arbitrarily in text and there's nothing stopping a "line" of highlighted text being broken into several runs. So you may need to check for *adjacent* runs with the same `.highlight_color` value to "assemble" those into the same sequence of text in the "apparent" highlighted passage.

Comment: thank you for your response but I received such error `AttributeError: 'Run' object has no attribute 'highlight_color'` maybe you added some specific import?

Comment: Sorry, that needs to be `run.font.highlight_color`, I've edited my response.

Comment: and what you receive with `print(r.font.highlight_color)`? I received `None` :( I hope that  I will be able to get rgb for example or smth like that

Comment: That value is `None` when no highlight color has been applied. This will usually be the case because most text is not highlighted. If you get `None` on a run you can see is highlighted, the "highlighting" may be done with a different mechanism like paragraph shading. Try making a short document with a highlighted passage and test with that.